# UIActivityViewController equivelant on Android

Tags: android, ios, facebook, twitter, share

Does Android have an equivalent built in control like UIActivityViewController on iOS? Are there any open source equivalents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is more based around `Intent` resolution so if more than one `Activity` on the device can handle an `Intent` for which you have set an `Action` and a `Category`, Android will automatically offer a list of Activities to the user to choose how they want to handle your data.  There may be other alternatives, but I just wanted to get this answer down so you can perhaps consider using the built in Android functionality.